# Carousel from Bootstrap 5 is not cycling through images on a timer or when clicked

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've taken some code directly from Bootstrap 5 to create a carousel, however for some reason the images won't cycle. I've tried multiple different images and I can't figure out why it isn't working. I've read the Bootstrap doc and I can't figure out what I'm missing. Carousel code:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.ane-vert.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/terace4096x2048.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/ce/0f/bf/l-ane-vert.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/ce/0f/bf/l-ane-vert.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Is there another step I'm missing, I've checked I'm using the correct version of Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I'm pretty new to this. Realised that I hadn't required Bootstrap in JS:

app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```html
import "bootstrap"
```

In the terminal:

yarn add @popperjs/core